# Laravel, can only flash error messages within controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this to **flash error messages** within my `UserController` (using `Toastr`);

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'     => 'required|max:200',
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. Auth::id(),
        'phone'    => 'alpha_num|nullable|min:8',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        Toastr::error('Changes not saved', 'Error');
        return back();

    }

    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->phone = $request->input('phone');

    $user->save();

    Toastr::success('Changes saved', 'OK');

    return back();

}
```

I would like to use Form Request for my `validation`, but keep running into problems when trying to flash (`toastr`) error messages.

Do one of you have an example of toastr used with Form Request? I have read the documentation like 10 times, but can't find a solution :(

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

This used to work about a year ago, but not anymore:

```
# Error messages
protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
{

    $messages = $validator->messages();

    foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
    {
        Toastr::error($message, 'Fejl');
    }

    return $validator->errors()->all();
}
```

Comment: what problems are you running in?

Comment: I can't make toastr show the error, using a Form Request. Laravel post no errors, just return to the form without displaying anything. Going to update my post with example code, that used to work.

Comment: I guess my main problem is how to grab the error and use it with Toastr - when using Form Request.

Comment: If you echo something like `{{ $errors->all() }}` (within a `@if ($errors->any())` to prevent errors), do you see any errors at all?

Comment: i always use sessions for error messages.

Comment: Yes, this show the error in my blade file.
if ($errors->any())

          foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            {{ $error }}
          endforeach
        endif
. Do you know how to make it work with Toastr in Form Request?

Answer (score 1):

Use `withValidator()` in your form request

but I am using toaster package from `yoeunes/toastr`

```
 public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $messages = $validator->messages();

        foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
        {
            toastr()->error ( $message, 'Error');
        }

        return $validator->errors()->all();

    }
```

It works for me in Laravel 7.x

Try that, thanks!

Comment: Works for me too! I'm using laravel 8.x